# The specified child already has a parent - implementing FloatingActionMenu

Tags: java, android, imageview, material-design, floating-action-button

I am trying to implement the circular floating action menu found [here](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu) but as soon as I ran the app, I got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I am very new to Android material design and implementing custom animations etc. I have seen similar questions to this but each question seems to be for a specific context.

This is my OnCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        ImageView icon = new ImageView(this); // Create an icon
        icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha));

        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(icon)
                .build();

        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        ImageView itemIcon1 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha));
        SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon1).build();
        ImageView itemIcon2 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_dark_touch));
        SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2).build();
        ImageView itemIcon3 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_selector));
        SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2).build();

        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(button1)
                .addSubActionView(button2)
                .addSubActionView(button3)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageView itemIcon2 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_dark_touch));
        SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2).build();
        ImageView itemIcon3 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_selector));
        SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2).build();
```

`itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2)` is called twice :P
the last line should be `itemIcon3`

Comment: Well that was silly.. Still getting used to this stuff.